# Pandas change format of data

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So, I have python script that convert a .xls or a .xlsx file into a csv:

```
df = pd.read_excel(input_name, sheet_name)

df.to_csv(output_name, sep=';', index=False, quotechar='\'', decimal='')
```

During the conversion, the data of the input_name file where the value was an integer become the same integer with an extra '0' at the end. And the float values (represented like this: 10,0548415184 for example but with variable length) loses there separator (,) and become an int with extra 0s as well.

As an example this input:

```
1000    98,762154966389  0,00   0,00    98,76   ABC_NAME
```

Will become:

```
10000   9876215496638900    0   0   9876215496638900   ABC_NAME
```

Why? How can I solve this?

desired output should be the same as the input (but in csv rather than xls / xlsx)

EDIT: nuriselcuk gave me the answer and now it works fine.

Thanks !

code should be:

```
df.to_csv(output_name, sep=';', index=False, quotechar='\'', decimal=',')
```

Comment: You cannot recognize characters as decimal, use decimal=','

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use `decimal=','` in order to recognize decimals